# Call a method at a specific time UWP

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, uwp

Im developing a UWP app and need to call a method once a day.

I use this right now and it work great:

```
public void SetTimeToShowNotification(DateTime date)
{
    var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan ts;
    if (date > dateNow)
        ts = date - dateNow;
    else
    {
        date = getNextDate(date);
        ts = date - dateNow;
    }
    //waits certan time and run the code
    Task.Delay(ts).ContinueWith((x) =>
    {
        //run the code at the time
        CheckPremieres();

        //setup call next day
        SetTimeToShowNotification(getNextDate(date));

    });
}
private DateTime getNextDate(DateTime date)
{
    if (App.laddaInEnGang)
    {
        return date.AddSeconds(20);
    }
    return date.AddDays(1);
}
```

The one thing i dont have tested yet is if it still fire if the app is put to the background..
Im also afraid that this will consume the battery on a phone, i have read about background task but dont know how to implement it...

The questions is are my method battery heavy?? Will the method be called from backgound?
Is there a better way of doing this, which in that case?

Comment: I would try taking a look at the [UWP samples for background tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask).

Comment: thx mike z! I will look in to it :).. why did I get a -1?? Was my question that bad?